# Multi-layer Dense Output Keras

Tags: keras, neural-network

is it possible in Keras to build network with 3 output Dense layers (with 10 neurons each)? 
If yes could you give me any suggestions how?

Comment: Sure, have a look at to Functional API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, something like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

input_layer  = Input(shape=(20,))

shared_layer = Dense(20)(input_layer)
output1      = Dense(10)(shared_layer)
output2      = Dense(10)(shared_layer)
output3      = Dense(10)(shared_layer)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[output1, output2, output3])
print(model.summary())


import numpy as np
a  = np.random.randn(10,20)
b1 = np.random.rand(10,10)
b2 = np.random.rand(10,10)
b3 = np.random.rand(10,10)

model.compile(optimiser='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(a, [b1,b2,b3], epochs=10)
```

(with random data)

You might want to adapt the loss function, depending on your actual targets.